# Is it necessary to have a set of objects nested in a named object

Tags: json, api, rest, response

What is the right way to format your responses in JSON and why? I've seen different services do it two ways, consider a simple `GET` `/users` resource:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "User created successfully",
    "data": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "John"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "George"},
        {"id": 3, "name": "Bob"},
        {"id": 4, "name": "Jane"}
    ]
}
```

That is how I usually do that. I have some abstract helper fields like `success` and `message`, there may be some more but the question is if should I nest the data in the `data` field to an array called the same way as the resource - `users`:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "User created successfully",
    "data": {
        "users": [
            {"id": 1, "name": "John"},
            {"id": 2, "name": "George"},
            {"id": 3, "name": "Bob"},
            {"id": 4, "name": "Jane"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Even if we don't use the abstraction:

```
{
    "users": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "John"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "George"},
        {"id": 3, "name": "Bob"},
        {"id": 4, "name": "Jane"}
    ]
}
```

Seems the `users` key is obsolete as any client will know the route they called, which consists of `/users`, where users are mentioned, and the client code like

```
$users = $request->perform('http://this.api/users')->body()->json_decode();
```

looks much better than

```
$users = $request->perform('http://this.api/users')->body()->json_decode()->users;
```

as it avoids repeated `users`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One use case where the envelope can be useful is when you are expecting to be dealing with large lists and need to do pagination to prevent huge response payloads. The envelope is a good place to put the pagination meta data:

```
{
    "users": [...],
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 50,
    "total": 10000
}
```

(This is what we do in a RESTful API I'm working on)

Clearly this is only relevant for requests that return lists of things (e.g. `/users/`) and not for requests that return single entities (e.g. `/users/42`) and even for requests that return lists, you don't *have* to use an envelope - one alternative would be to use response headers for this meta data instead.

PS. I would only advise having a `success` and `message` fields if you have a concrete use case for them. Otherwise don't bother, they are simply unnecessary.

Comment: Your answer is more on the topic then the others. Yes, I haven't mentioned the offset, limit, total and some other descriptors that we use. Enveloping is great, but I mean the whole structure is that the key `users` being repeated twice - first time in the request URL and in the body of the response itself

Comment: What is your question? If you need an envelope for things like pagination of the root array, then you need a key that the client must specify - there is no getting round that. It doesnt need to be called `users` it could be called something like `items` for all resource types. If you don't need the envelope then there is no problem.

Comment: Exactly, sometimes they don't use default like `data` or `items`, but use `users` that change per-resource. That's what I'm asking - is there any reason to do it that way?

Comment: Ah, I see :) None that I can think of. Sorry I can't help with that one.

Answer (score 2):

Just to get on the same page, `data` is a field in a JSON object. In the first example the value of `data` is an array. In the second example the value of `data` is an object.

Either is valid, so to answer your question: no it is not necessary to nest named objects in an named object. It is necessary that all fields of an object be named, but you are free to nest arrays within an object.

It really just depends on what the processor expects. If `data` can be anything, then the first approach is fine. If code expects the value of the `data` field to be an object, then you have to use something like the second example.

Comment: I may have not explained my problem really well, but this is not what I'm looking for. I ask not about the syntax, but rather the ideological part - should there be the upper "root" element `users` in the JSON data

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment which you added to first comment: more descriptive data is better data as every information is useful for consumer of you API - REST endpoint. So if you know that the content is user, or whatever, it's better to use it in schema or endpoint url.

Better description = better consuption :-)

Comment: I understand that, but it's repeating, not describing, and I can't understand why so many API services do that

Comment: You mean why they provide as most descriptive data as possible?

Comment: I mean it's not descriptive as it's a repetition. If you request a resource named `users` why would you need to refer to the `users` object property to get the actual users list